# Javascript: Strange type conversion

Tags: javascript, jquery, types, numbers, typeof

I have the following code to simply change a Number value:

```
//zoom select
var zoom = 1;
$('select#zoom').change(function(e) {
    zoom = $(this).val();       
    console.log('zooming to: ', Math.floor(zoom*100), '%'); 
});

//zoom incremental  
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    //out
      if(e.keyCode == 45){
        if (zoom > 0) zoom = parseInt(zoom,10) - 0.1;
        $('select#zoom').val(zoom);
        console.log('zooming to: ', Math.floor(zoom*100), '%'); 
        console.log('Type:',typeof zoom,' ',toString(zoom)); //*flag
      }
    //in
      if(e.keyCode == 43){
        if (zoom < 2) zoom = parseInt(zoom,10) + 0.1;
        $('select#zoom').val(zoom);
        console.log('zooming to: ', Math.floor(zoom*100), '%');
        console.log('Type:',typeof zoom,' ',toString(zoom)); //*flag
      }
    
});
```

It behaves as expected when the keypress event fires, however if I start with using the select element and then press a key to change the values, the output appears as such:

> zooming to: 50%
>
> zooming to: NaN%
>
> Type: number   [object Window]

HTML:

```
<select id="zoom">
            <option value="2">200%</option>
            <option value="1.5">150%</option>
            <option value="1.25">125%</option>
            <option value="1" selected>100%</option>
            <option value=".75">75%</option>
            <option value=".5">50%</option>
            <option value=".25">25%</option>            
        </select>
```

This is driving me nuts. Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like this line is where the problem starts `zoom = $(this).val();`. You should make sure it is a number at that point.

Comment: I have tried using `zoom = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);` but strangely enough it loses the value i.e perhaps convert it to undefined or null.

Comment: `zoom = $(this).val();` saves a string, you need to convert it to a proper type of number - for sure it would be better to save it as a number at first place (when onchange is triggered), so you do not have to convert it over and over agian. For further info see my answer.

Comment: @JanLegner That did it! Smart guy you are. TA

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `parseInt`, you should use `parseFloat`

```
parseInt(".25"); // returns NaN, because first char is not a valid char considering we are reading integer
parseFloat(".25") // returns 0.25
```

Also note that for integers (such as `"2"`, `"1"`) your solution works. It fails when trying to parse floats (`".25"`)